# What does this Java syntax mean? (`Class<? extends ContactAccessor> clazz`)

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have been developing android applications for about 1 month now I am getting pretty familiar with the Java syntax but today I stumbled upon this piece of code :

```
try {
    Class<? extends ContactAccessor> clazz =
                      Class.forName(className).asSubclass(ContactAccessor.class);
    sInstance = clazz.newInstance();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
}
```

Could somebody explain me what this  `Class<? extends ContactAccessor> clazz` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you have a Class which is ContactAccessor class or a sub class of that class or interface.

Since you have `ContactAccessor.class` already, I would assume you have a sub class.

Answer (score 2):

`Class` is used for reflection. `<>` means generic type. `?` is a generic wildcard. Combined this means that `clazz` represents definition of a class which is a descendant of `ContactAccessor`. For further explanations, google for `generics`, `wildcards` and `reflection`.

Answer (score 0):

That means that you use a class which extend a special base class. This is also called Generics in Java.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the `Class` you need,it's type is unknown(hence the `?`). But you know one property of it - that it is a subclass of `ContactAccessor`. And you need to find that particular class - so you do :  `Class.forName(className).asSubclass(ContactAccessor.class);` saying fetch me the class by it's class,which is a subclass of `ContactAccessor`.

Answer (score 0):

That is an example of Java Generics (more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypeinference.html)). It implies that the `clazz` variable will be of a type which extends `ContactAccessor`.

Answer (score 0):

It defines a variable `clazz` that is a `Class` object of a generic class that extends the `ContactAccessor` class.

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard ( "?" ) is used so that the Class will only accept the classes extended by ContactAccessor, only that but also any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Any class that is `subclass` of `ContactAccessor` class.